# Why is the predefined macro __STDC_VERSION__ undefined?

Tags: c, visual-c++, c99

I want to know which C standard I am currently using in my Visual Studio C++, but I have a trouble using the `__STDC_VERSION__` predefined macro and other C99 predefined macros - an error indicating that this identifier is not defined appears and when I used `#ifndef __STDC_VERSION__` it seems that it is not defined. Does this mean that I am using ANSI C?

Below is a sample code for using `__STDC_VERSION__`:

```
int main(void) {
   printf("%d\n", __STDC_VERSION__);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `__STDC_VERSION__` is spelled with one underscore in the middle, not two.

Comment: `__STDC_VERSION__` was not in the original 1989 C standard; if you're going to use it at all, you should check whether it is defined first (with `#ifdef`).

Comment: In my text book, __STDC__VERSION__ is spelled with two underscores in the middle, and even for one underscore in the middle it does not work as well.

Comment: @user2357112 That's not the issue.  MSVC doesn't support the macro.  It's reproducible and not a typographical error.  Please reconsider the "on hold".

Comment: @AhmedHesham That is an error in your textbook (probably a simple typo).  Textbooks are not infallible.

Comment: Thank you all for your appreciated comments, please consider the "on hold".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only C standard that Visual C++ supports fully is the ANSI-89/ISO-90 first standard.  There is no official support for C99 or C11; but there is enough of C99 supported to make C++11 and C++14 work.

What I use for source code portability is `#ifdef _MSC_VER` and expect only C89/C90 support if that's defined.  (If you need finer detail, you can test the value of _MSC_VER to see which version.  There's a [list of MSC/C++ versions and their _MSC_VER values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B#Internal_version_numbering) at Wikipedia.

Obviously, that has to be tested before any of the C99 or C11 macros.  As a special note, if a Microsoft compiler defines `__STDC__` then you don't get even partial support for C99.  That macro is only defined when compiling with the `/Za` option, which disables any Microsoft extensions--including C++/C99 bits like `//` comments, mixed declarations and code in a block, or declarations in `for` statements.

Comment: Visual C/C++ implements the C89 language standard plus the parts of C99/C11 C Runtime Library required for C++11/14/17 . For C++11/14/17 language conformance, see [the Visual C++ documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance) as well as [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/04/09/msvc-now-correctly-reports-__cplusplus/).

Comment: If you read the comments in [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/07/06/msvc-preprocessor-progress-towards-conformance/), you'll see that there are plans to support C11 in the Visual C/C++ product but the first step is to get a fully C99 conforming preprocessor which also is the last remaining part of C++11/C++14 conformance that is missing.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn That is what I said, isn't it?  They support just the part of C they need for C++ to move on.  Thanks for the blog link, though.  I note that they don't say when to expect "full C11 conformance".  It's just "on the roadmap."  Not holding my breath.

Comment: The comments helped clarifying the reason, thank you.